# Artificial Propagation and it's relation to asexual reproduction

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

I know that asexual reproduction is also called vegetative reproduction. However I do not understand it's relation to artificial propagation. Is it a technique used for asexual reproduction (the method by which plants reproduce asexually) or is artificial propagation another name for asexual reproduction.

Am I right when I say artificial propagation techniques provide the means for plants to reproduce asexually?

Also, is my understanding of asexual reproduction and artificial propagation correct:

In asexual reproduction, a parent plant produces offspring that are genetically identical to it and to each other. Asexual reproduction produces clones as the offspring and the parent are clones of one another. Asexual reproduction can be an advantage when environmental conditions are stable and an organism is well-adapted to its environment. The genetically identical off spring will also be adapted to that environment. Asexual reproduction is carried out by the different artificial propagation techniques. Artificial propagation is the cloning of a plant from a portion of its roots, stems, or leaves. In asexual reproduction in plants, also called vegetative propagation, new individuals are grown from a portion of the roots, stems, or leaves of the existing plant. Artificial propagation involves using plants’ natural ability to reproduce vegetative. This process enables farmers and gardeners to select the parent plants for specific traits.

Answer (score 2):

Artificial propagation is (generally) human-directed, while asexual/vegetative reproduction is a natural process. Take a look at the wikipedia article on [vegetative reproduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetative_reproduction#Artificial_vegetative_propagation) for more information on how and why artificial propagation is sometimes preferred to vegetative reproduction.

Comment: You can also have a look on the [artificial reproduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_reproduction) article in the Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Artificial propagation is the cloning of a plant from a portion of its roots, stems and leaves. It does nor use reproductive organs of a plant to propagate.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. We're looking for long answers that provide explanation, context, and include references to reliable sources. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right with appropriate citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed especially when they are a poor duplicate of an already existing answer. Please take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then delete or [edit] your answer accordingly.